# Failed to load site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```html
<?php

require_once("core/config.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<meta name="author" content="Slent">
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="1A6F186BE63EEA129AB7C25BB82391D1">
<title><?php echo $nombre; ?> - Tus pixeles en buenas manos</title>
<link href="<?php echo $url; ?>media/css/origem.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $url; ?>media/scripts/general.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bar_blue"></div>
<div id="banner_itens">
 <div id="alinha">
  <div id="space_public">
      </div>
  <!--  <div id="login">
    <form id="form_login" action="<?php echo $url; ?>index.php#" method="post">
   <div id="espaco_inputs">
    <input id="user_login" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" onclick="if(this.value==&#39;Usuario&#39;) this.value=&#39;&#39;" onblur="if(this.value==&#39;&#39;) this.value=&#39;Usuario&#39;">
    <input id="pass_login" type="password" placeholder="Usuário">
    <div class="forget"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>opcoes/recupere-sua-senha" style="color:#fff;">¿Olvidó su contraseña?</a></div>
   </div>
   <div id="opcoes">
    <input id="logar_s" value=" " type="submit">
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>cadastrar"><div id="cadastro"></div></a>
   </div>
  </form>
    </div> -->
 </div>
</div>
<div id="bar_fine">
 <div style="width:1000px; margin:0pt auto;">
  <div id="text"><span class="last_tweet"><!-- Carregando último tweet... --></span>
    <div class="back_form">

<div id="twitter_div">
<div id="twitter_update_list">
</div>
</div>
</div></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
 <div style="width:1000px; margin:0pt auto;">
  <div id="seta_right" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  <div id="text">
   <div style="width:99999px; height:auto;" id="menu_cell">
    <div class="item"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>http://habbolacha.esy.es/">&nbsp;Inicio&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a rel="c_tropihabbo" href="<?php echo $url; ?>index.php#">&nbsp;<?php echo $nombre; ?>&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/22">&nbsp;Catálogo&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a rel="c_pixelart" href="<?php echo $url; ?>equipe">&nbsp;Equipe</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a rel="c_habbohotel" href="<?php echo $url; ?>habbo">Habbo</a></div>
   </div>
   <div id="m_tropihabbo" class="submenu_item" style="margin-top:40px; margin-left:30px;">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>tropihabbo/equipe">Equipo</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>tropihabbo/historia">Historia</a></li>
   </div>
   <div id="m_habbohotel" class="submenu_item" style="margin-top:40px; margin-left:270px;">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>habbohotel/habbo">Habbo Hotel</a></li>
   </div>
   <div id="m_fancenter" class="submenu_item" style="margin-top:40px; margin-left:58px;">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>fancenter/imager">Habbo Imager</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>fancenter/meme">Generador de Memes</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>fancenter/beijo">Generador de Besos</a></li>
   </div>
   <div id="m_ajuda" class="submenu_item" style="margin-top:40px; margin-left:128px;">
        <li><script language="JavaScript"> function abrir(URL) {  var width = 623;  var height = 513;  var left = 99;  var top = 99;  window.open(URL,'janela', 'width='+width+', height='+height+', top='+top+', left='+left+', scrollbars=no, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no'); } </script><a href="javascript:abrir('/ajuda/contato/client.php?locale=en&style=simplicity');">Contato</a></li>
   </div>
   <div id="m_opcoes" class="submenu_item" style="margin-top:40px; margin-left:200px;">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>registro">Regístrate!</a></li>
       </div>
   <div id="m_pixelart" class="submenu_item" style="margin-top:40px; margin-left:-35px;">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>pixelarts">Oficina de pixel arts</a></li>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="seta_left" style="opacity: 0.5; cursor: pointer;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="bar_gray">
 <div style="width:1000px; margin:0pt auto; height:121px;">
  <div id="content">
     <?php $lol = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias LIMIT 3"); while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($lol)){?><div id="evento">
    <div id="imagem" style="background: url(<?php echo $data['imagen']; ?>) center;"></div>
    <div id="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" style="color:#585858;"><?php echo utf8_decode($data['nombre']); ?></a></div>
   </div><?php } ?>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="content_init">
 <?php if($page == 'catalogo' || $page == 'panel'){?>
    <style>
 #item_cat {
  width:222px;
  height:26px;
  float:left;
  margin-top:1px;
  background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/imagens/item_valores_cat.png);
 }
 
 #item_cat .titulo {
  width:190px; 
  height:12px;
  margin-top:6px; 
  float:left; 
  margin-left:3px; 
  font-family:Verdana; 
  font-size:11px; 
  font-weight:bold; 
  color:#666; 
  text-shadow:1px 1px #ECECEC; 
  text-align:left;
 }
 
 #item_cat .titulo a {
  color:#666;
 }
 
 #espaco_todo {
  width:681px;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0px auto;
 }
 
 #item_cotacao {
  width:224px;
  height:43px;
  background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/imagens/item_valores.png);
  float:left;
  margin-right:3px; margin-top:3px;
 }
 
 #item_cotacao .imagem {
  width:34px;
  height:40px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:3px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 #item_cotacao .dados {
  width:160px;
  height:40px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:2px;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

 #item_cotacao .dados .titulo {
  width:160px;
  height:14px;
  float:left;
  margin-top:3px;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#004A5E;
  text-shadow:1px 1px #FFF;
 }

 #item_cotacao .dados .descricao {
  width:160px;
  height:14px;
  float:left;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#999999;
  text-shadow:1px 1px #FFF;
 }

 #item_cotacao .icon_up {
  width:11px;
  height:14px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:4px;
  margin-top:12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/imagens/icons_cotacao.png);
 }

 #item_cotacao .icon_down {
  width:11px;
  height:14px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:4px;
  margin-top:12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/imagens/icons_cotacao.png) +22px;
 }

 #item_cotacao .icon_stop {
  width:9px;
  height:10px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:4px;
  margin-top:15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/imagens/icons_cotacao.png) +10px;
 }
 </style>
 <?php } ?>
 <div id="left">
  <?php if($page == 'normal' || $page == 'reglas' || $page == 'noticias'){?>
  <div id="player_left">
   <!-- //Cms sin nombre xD. Por MoNiKoS. !-->
   <div id="items_avatar">
    <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url(https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&amp;user=<?php echo $radio_locutor; ?>&amp;action=std&amp;direction=2&amp;head_direction=3&amp;gesture=sml&amp;size=s); background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: initial initial;"></div>
    <div id="items">
     <div class="locutor">
      <div class="texto"><?php echo $radio_locutor; ?></div>
     </div>
     <div class="programa">
      <div class="texto"><?php echo $radio_programa; ?></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="outros">
     <div id="botoes">
      <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['radio'])){$_SESSION['radio'] = 'play';} if($_SESSION['radio'] == 'play'){ echo '<iframe src="http://tropihabbo.es/player.php" width="0" height="0"  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe><br />'; } ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>player/play.php"><div class="play"></div></a>
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>player/pause.php"><div class="pause"></div></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
   <div id="content">
    <div id="top">Catálogo</div>
    <?php
    $lolol = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_catalogo ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($lolol)){?>
    <div id="item_valores_left">
     <div class="imagem" style="background: url(<?php echo $data['imagen']; ?>) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="dados">
      <div class="titulo"><?php echo utf8_decode($data['nombre']); ?></div>
      <div class="descricao"><?php echo $data['precio']; ?></div>
     </div>
     <?php if($data['actual'] == '0'){?>
     <div class="icon_down"></div>
     <?php } elseif($data['actual'] == '1'){?>
     <div class="icon_stop"></div>
     <?php } elseif($data['actual'] == '2'){?>
     <div class="icon_up"></div>
     <?php } ?>
    </div><?php } ?>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
   <div id="content">
    <div id="top">Habbo destacado</div>
    <?php $lol2 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM habbo_destacado LIMIT 1"));?>
    <div id="users_highlights">
     <div class="avatar" style="background: url(https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&amp;user=<?php echo $lol2['nombre']; ?>&amp;action=crr=2&amp;direction=2&amp;head_direction=3&amp;gesture=sml) -10px;"></div>
     <div class="dados">
      <div class="habbo"><a href="http://habbo.com.br/home/Ennriquee" style="color:#969696" vlink="#969696" alink="#969696"><?php echo $lol2['nombre']; ?></a></div>
      <div class="descricao"><?php echo utf8_decode($lol2['cuerpo']); ?></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box">
   <div id="content">
    <div id="top">Publicidad</div></div></div><?php }elseif($page == 'catalogo'){ ?>
    <div id="box">
   <div id="content">
    <div id="top">Categorías</div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/c9bf51af242c7599d6fcedc6f2d95faa.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/22">Ecotron</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/4e81c31d0917d11c3f92efc91fbff3c7.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/30">Furni Matic</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/1c20dc66af8c60981d8875c603621d7b.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/93">Galería</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/3db82150e984d679e97b967ff3464a17.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/36">Habbo Cambio</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/531dd47769045b3264baea26f9383116.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/57">Mega raros</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/50d87cd92bd4403f22fb76ec7b2e2ddf.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/72">Raros</a></div>
    </div>
    <!-- //Cms sin nombre xD. Por MoNiKoS. !-->
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/b8bb1bccbd823e85b7e50249c0b3609e.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/37">Raros del HC</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/4782311b2736911fa77adfeddc6020ac.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/73">Raros edición limitada</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div style="width:26px; height:26px; float:left; background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>media/upload/valores/76f2cc0821e9260d21b93391c6645468.png) center no-repeat;"></div>
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>catalogo/categoria/74">Regalos del HC</a></div>
    </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  <?php }elseif($page == 'panel'){ ?>
  <div id="box">
   <div id="content">
    <div id="top">Categorías</div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>admin_noticias">Administrar noticias</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>admin_noticias?do=create">Crear noticias</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>admin_admin">Administradores</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>admin_catalogo">Administrar catálogo</a></div>
    </div>
    <!-- //Cms sin nombre xD. Por MoNiKoS. !-->
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>admin_destacado.php?do=edit">Editar Habbo Destacado</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_cat">
     <div class="titulo"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>admin_logout">Desconectarse</a></div>
    </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
 </div>
 <?php if($page == 'normal'){?>
 <div id="center">
  <!-- <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>cadastrar"><div id="fred_inicial"></div></a> !-->
  <?php } else {?>
  <div id="center">
   <?php } ?>
```

Hello, I have a problem with my site, it does not load layout and I don't know how to solve this error :

> Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I'll be leaving my site link for you to see how you are and the code

Link:http://www.habbomania.esy.es/menu.php

Comment: specify your problem in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are getting in console/network tab is two files not being able to load, due to an incorrect URL. The URL It's trying to goto is

```
http://xn--link%20do%20seu%20f%20site-6gc/media/css/origem.css
```

*Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED*

And

```
http://xn--link%20do%20seu%20f%20site-6gc/media/scripts/general.js
```

*Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED*

These are being called from

```
<link href="<?php echo $url; ?>media/css/origem.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And likewise with the JS file,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $url; ?>media/scripts/general.js"></script>
```

Correct the `$url` variable to point to the correct address for these files and then you will no longer get the error.